# Morphological Watershed From Markers filter on ITK

Tags: c++, image-processing, image-segmentation, itk, watershed

I'm trying to create a pipeline for image segmentation, with the libraries from ITK. But, when I apply the itkMorphologicalWatershedFromMarkersFilter, the result is a blank image (binary image with only 1's).

Does anyone know how to apply this filter correctly?

My input image should be the gradient of an image, and the marker image should be the result of the application of a watershed filter on the same image.

input [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOHZa.jpg)

marker [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7ZRF.jpg)

And this is the declaration and the application of the filter:

```
typedef itk::MorphologicalWatershedFromMarkersImageFilter < OutputImageType, OutputImageType >
      MorphologicalWatershedFromMarkersImageFilterType;

MorphologicalWatershedFromMarkersImageFilterType::Pointer CwatershedFilter
      = MorphologicalWatershedFromMarkersImageFilterType::New();


CwatershedFilter->SetInput1(reader1->GetOutput());
CwatershedFilter->SetMarkerImage(reader2->GetOutput());

CwatershedFilter->SetMarkWatershedLine(true);

try{

    CwatershedFilter->Update();

}
catch (itk::ExceptionObject & error)
{
    std::cerr << "Error: " << error << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Also, this is the link to the documentation of this filter, from itk.org:

http://www.itk.org/Doxygen48/html/classitk_1_1MorphologicalWatershedFromMarkersImageFilter.html#a20e3b8de42219606ba759e822be0aaa2

Thank you so much!!

Comment: It would help if you pasted relevant code.

Comment: There's the code. I don't know if it would help, but I also pasted the link to the documentation of the filter.

Comment: If you feed your code a simpler image, will the filter work? For example, try setting a black image with a white square in the middle as input and see if your code produces the right result.
This will help establish if the problem is with the code or the input.

Comment: I tried that, it gives the same result :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not C++ ITK, there is a SimpleITK Notebooks which demonstrates it's usage:

http://insightsoftwareconsortium.github.io/SimpleITK-Notebooks/32_Watersheds_Segmentation.html

Your marker image is just binary, and not a label image. By that I mean your image is only 0 and 1 ( or 255). In the linked example note the following:

```
min_img = sitk.RegionalMinima(feature_img, backgroundValue=0, foregroundValue=1.0, fullyConnected=False, flatIsMinima=True)
marker_img = sitk.ConnectedComponent(min_img, fullyConnected=False)
```

The "min_img" is a binary image, but then the image is processed with the "ConnectedComponent" image filter, which gives each "island" a unique number. This is what is expected for the marker ( or label ) image for the WatershedFromMarker filter.

I will also note that your input image has some boundary lines, that you may not want as input.

Comment: thank you for that example. My feature is the gradient of the original. And the marker image is a binary image with some pre-processing.

Comment: I edited the question for a better view of the images

Comment: So, my input image shouldn't have boundary lines? But how may I remove those lines? Or which image should I use? The original RGB one, or the grayscale? I didn't understand that. Thank you so much for the help!